# Editing image using double-loop (weight and height)

Tags: android, image, bitmap, pixel

I want to edit pixels around the middle of the picture and for that i need double loop of x and y each represents the height or weight of the image bitmap. This is an example:

```
for(x = 0; x < bm.getWeight(); x++)
{
    for(y = 0; y < bm.getHeight(); y++)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

The problem is that the method getPixles works as an array whose length is the weight*height and then the loop looks like that:

```
int [] pixels = new int [bm.getWidth() * bm.getHeight()];
for(x = 0; y < pixels.length; x++)
{
    //
}
```

I hope you guys understand what i am trying to explaing.
So is there a way to seperate it to a double loop or get the middle pixels with another way?
Thanks a lot ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
int width = bm.getWidth();
int height = bm.getHeight();

int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
int curPixel;

for (int columnNum = 0; columnNum < width; columnNum++) {
    for (int rowNum = 0; rowNum < height; rowNum++) {
        curPixel = pixels[rowNum * width + columnNum];
        // do stuff with curPixel
    }
}
```